# Google GWT error 404

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, gwt

I am trying to run a sample program from the book: "Google App Engine Java and GWT Application Development Code."

The program called connactr.

The program is using the imports:
com.google.appengine.api.labs.taskqueue.TaskOptions.Builder.url
com.google.appengine.api.labs.taskqueue.Queue

That do not exist anymore, so I changed them to: 
com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.TaskOptions.Builder.withurl
com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.*

I also change the code:

```
Queue queue = QueueFactory.getDefaultQueue();
      queue.add(url("/updatefeedurls").payload(data,
        "application/x-java-serialized-object"));
```

to:

```
Queue queue = QueueFactory.getDefaultQueue();
      queue.add(withUrl("/updatefeedurls").payload(data,
        "application/x-java-serialized-object"));
```

I made these kind of changes everywhere I had the old methods.
I was able to run the application, with no errors, but for every page I receive error 404, page not found.

I assume that the withurl() method has different logic that causes the error 404, but I wasn't able to find what I should do to fix it.

What should I change in order to make this work?

Here is the web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee       
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"   
id="WebApp_ID"
version="2.5">


<!-- ===================== friendsService ===================== -->
<servlet>
<servlet-name>friendsService</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.metadot.book.connectr.server.FriendsServiceImpl</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>friendsService</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/connectr/friendsService</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- ===================== messagesService ===================== -->
<servlet>
<servlet-name>messagesService</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.metadot.book.connectr.server.MessagesServiceImpl</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>messagesService</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/connectr/messagesService</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- ===================== Login Service ===================== -->
<servlet>
<servlet-name>loginService</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.metadot.book.connectr.server.LoginServiceImpl</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>loginService</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/connectr/loginService</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<!-- ===================== Login Google Servlet ===================== -->

<servlet>
<servlet-name>logingoogle</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.metadot.book.connectr.server.servlets.LoginGoogleServlet</servlet-  
class>
 </servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>logingoogle</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/logingoogle</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>logingooglecallback</servlet-name>
<servlet-  
class>com.metadot.book.connectr.server.servlets.LoginGoogleCallbackServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>logingooglecallback</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/logingooglecallback</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

<!-- ===================== Login Twitter Servlet ===================== -->

<servlet>
<servlet-name>logintwitter</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.metadot.book.connectr.server.servlets.LoginTwitterServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>logintwitter</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/logintwitter</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>logintwittercallback</servlet-name>
<servlet- 
class>com.metadot.book.connectr.server.servlets.LoginTwitterCallbackServlet</servlet-    
Class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>logintwittercallback</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/logintwittercallback</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

 <!-- ===================== Login Facebook Servlet ===================== -->

<servlet>
<servlet-name>loginfacebook</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.metadot.book.connectr.server.servlets.LoginFacebookServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>loginfacebook</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/loginfacebook</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>






 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>XMPPRequest</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/xmpprequest</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

 <security-constraint>
 <web-resource-collection>
  <url-pattern>/xmpprequest</url-pattern>
 </web-resource-collection>
 <auth-constraint>
  <role-name>admin</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
 </security-constraint>



<filter-mapping> 
<filter-name>appstats</filter-name> 
 <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
</filter-mapping> 

<servlet>
 <servlet-name>appstats</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.AppstatsServlet</servlet-class> 
</servlet>
 <servlet-mapping> 
 <servlet-name>appstats</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/appstats/*</url-pattern> 
 </servlet-mapping>

 <security-constraint> 
  <web-resource-collection> 
  <url-pattern>/appstats/*</url-pattern> 
  </web-resource-collection> 
  <auth-constraint> 
  <role-name>admin</role-name> 
  </auth-constraint> 
</security-constraint> -->

<!-- Default page to serve -->
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>ConnectrApp.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>


</web-app>
```

Thank you in advance,
Idan.

Comment: It would be better attach information related to web.xml , firebug console information on 404 error. Retagging with google-app-engine tag.

Comment: Monitor the request in Firebug Console or Chrome Dev tools to check on what URL the request is fired to. withURL function might be slightly modifying the URL that is leaving your web.xml mapping incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking that withUrl requires the entrire Url to work as intended and not the relative location. Fortunately GWT provides with a way to make the entire url in a dynamic way.

Try the TaskOptions `getUrl()` method. Use `Window.alert(url-derived-from-getUrl)` and check what the url built with `withUrl` is.

You can use

```
GWT.getHostPageBaseUrl();

GWT.getModuleBaseUrl();
```

to build your url properly inside withUrl(Sting url).